# Facebook android app v 3.1 not fetching date of birth and gender

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am tired to get date of birth and user gender in my android app by using Facebook SDK. I am using Facebook Sdk v. 4.5.1 and as a app in developer.facebook.com there is a 3.1 version in my app. in the test mode on
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/1767621746608224?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dbirthday&version=v3.1

I saw that, I can not get my own information such as dob, gender and some more but when i change it's version 3.1 to 2.7 everything gone great so, I just need to justify for version 3.1 what's the mater with version 3.1, how do I get my information in testing mode should I have review for those permission whether I am in test mode or is there any another problem please do share your suggestion as well as code if is there anything you've already done before.

Thanks in Advance Stack....

Comment: What permissions are you asking for?

Comment: Hello CBroe. thanks for you response. well my problem with dob and gender has been resolved but one more thing I need to know can I get user's mobile number by using facebook sdk for android? if yes please let me know about it's permission, and parameters for 4.5.1 SDK Version

Comment: No, that’s not possible.

Comment: Well, Thanks For the information.

Answer (score 0):

Since API version 3.0 you have to specifically ask for the new `user_gender` and `user_age_range` permissions during the login process.

The change is documented in the [changelog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0)

> Five new permissions have been added:
>
> - `user_gender` – for accessing a person's gender.
> - `user_age_range` – for accessing a person's age range.